# pass php variable value to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Im trying to pass the value of a php variable into javascript but i just cant get it to work. Am I doing anything wrong? Below is the line of code I'm working with.

```
var dist = parseInt("<?php echo json_encode($distance); ?>");
```

Comment: $distance contains an integer value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$distance is an integer? why don't you just write

```
var dist = <?php echo $distance; ?>
```

Comment: yes $distance contains an integer value

Comment: Absolutely correct. If `$distance` is a PHP Integer, there is no need to `json_encode`, wrap in quotes, or `parseInt`. Just spit it out.

Answer (score 1):

If the value in *$distance* is just an integer, you don't need the json_encode call.  You can just do a php echo of *$distance*.

Something like

```
var dist = <?php echo $distance; ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you right click > view html source in your web browser, you would see for yourself that you have an extra set of quotes.

And, good for you for using json_encode() to output it as a string. That's an excellent way to safely output a value to javascript. although, if its an integer, theres no need here.