# how to pass php parameter to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, parameters, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass php variable value to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437703/pass-php-variable-value-to-javascript)

I have a piece of php code

```
function formLetterTabPage($redirect_url, $letter){
  $test = 123;
  foreach (range('A','Z') as $val) {
    if($val == $letter){
        echo '<li class="a" id="li_'.$letter.'" onclick="tab_click('.$letter.')">'.$letter.'</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li class="b" id="li_'.$val.'" onclick="tab_click('.$letter.')">'.$val.'</li>';
    }
  }
}
```

and my javascript function tab_click is quite simple:

```
function tab_click(f){
  alert(f);
}
```

the key part is here:

```
echo '<li class="a" onclick="tab_click('.$letter.')">'.$letter.'</li>';
```

it cannot work out ! so I change it like this:

```
$test = 123;
echo '<li class="a" onclick="tab_click('.$test .')">'.$letter.'</li>';
```

it works perfert, and the page show me 123! I wonder why this happen? And I checked the html code, it ok:

```
<li class="navi_letter_leftb" id="li_A" onclick="tab_click(A)">A</li>
```

ok, I don't know why?

Comment: Because in your first sample you end up with `onclick="tab_click(A)"`. Not valid. Use manual quotes in the right content, or json_encode() or htmlspecialchars() for escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need additional quotes in your javascript for string parameters:

```
echo '<li class="a" onclick="tab_click(\''.$letter.'\')">'.$letter.'</li>';
```

In your test case `$test = 123;` you are passing an integer, so the quotes are not needed.

**EDIT**

Output without quotes (invalid javascript):

```
<li class="a" onclick="tab_click(a)">a</li>
```

Output with quotes:

```
<li class="a" onclick="tab_click('a')">a</li>
```

Comment: yes! that's right! thanks Mathieu, but why?

Comment: @diligent I added the HTML output to my answer. Argument in `tab_click(a)` *must* be quoted because it's a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `$test = 123` your javascript it's working because you're passing an integer value.

But your `$letter` it's a string and so the resulting html code it's wrong:

```
<li class="navi_letter_leftb" id="li_A" onclick="tab_click(A)">A</li>
```

You have to wrap your string between quotes `''`. So it should be:

```
<li class="navi_letter_leftb" id="li_A" onclick="tab_click('A')">A</li>
```

and you should change your code to:

```
echo '<li class="a" onclick="tab_click(\''.$letter.'\')">'.$letter.'</li>';
```

Comment: thanks Cirou, because i pass a string to a function , that's why I am wrong. Thanks.