# How to pass value from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass php variable value to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437703/pass-php-variable-value-to-javascript)

I want to create a progress bar, the value of the progress will be coming from PHP.

```
<div class="prog" id="progressbar"></div>
<label id="amount">
<?php echo $cast; ?></label>
```

I have this kind of javascript.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I throw the value $cast in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: <?php echo intval($cast);?>
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: but it is display the progress at this time. When $cast change the value, it isn't updated.

Comment: then you have to use ajax to update it repatedly

Comment: the progress bar did not change :(((

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is run in Client (browser), while PHP is run on server. You can't cast varble from PHP to javascript like that. 
 With print progress:

```
 <?php echo $cast; ?>
```

it just display the value of current run time, it is not updated.
If you have a link to check value of progress bar, just use ajax POST or GET to make change.